# Problem with image width in views/ block

Tags: media

I have a problem to set image dimension on various position. I want a 300x100px in top, 100x75px for thumbnail and other dimensions on other place. In WordPress I can just add "width" attribute to set image width, also class. Example: //img src="location" width="100" class="myclass" alt="". In drupal I can't found how to set this.

I know, I can set in image style with various dimension but too many dimensions. I think, it will increase my hosting disk.

**How to set width attribute on image in Drupal block/views** like [img src="location" width="value"]?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `hook_preprocess_image` in `template.php`

```
function <THEMENAME>_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    // If this image is of the type 'thumbnail' then assign additional classes to it:
    if ($variables['style_name'] == 'thumbnail') {
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'yourclass';
        $variables['attributes']['width'] = 'yourclass';
    }
}
```

OR

```
function <THEMENAME>_image_style($variables) {
  $style_name = $variables['style_name'];
  //print_r($variables);
  $path = $variables['path'];
  $style_path = image_style_path($style_name, $path);
  if (!file_exists($style_path)) {
    $style_path = image_style_url($style_name, $path);
  }
  $variables['path'] = $style_path;
  if (is_file($style_path)) {
    if (list($width, $height, $type, $attributes) = @getimagesize($style_path)) {
      $variables['attributes'] = array('class' => 'fullwidth');     
      $variables['width'] = '400px';
      $variables['height'] = '400px';
    }
  }
  return theme('image', $variables);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Nikhil. But, I'm still confuse, How can I use it in views/block? For example, I want use that function on my sidebar block. where I can set the width, and how to use it in other block with different dimension?

Comment: @sumedi, if you place this code in template.php you will be able to use it anywhere. The only way to limit this is with the `image-style` name. The Attribute will be automatically get added to the image. You cannot edit them through views/blocks.

Comment: thanks for your help. so, I have to make some image-style (may be two) for some purpose other than default image-style(thumbnail, medium, large). and I can set a class or width for each image-style. sorry, I'm new to drupal.

Comment: yes thats what i said.

Comment: I'm still found a problem. The code is added a class on my image_style, but I get warning: Notice: Undefined index: style_name in resep962_preprocess_image() (line 4 of /home/sumedi/public_html/drupal-7.17/sites/all/themes/resep962/template.php).

Comment: @sumedi, Try the second section. Can you please post the `$variables` here ?

Comment: `function resep962_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['style_name'] == 'thumbnail') {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'tleft';
   }
} `//resep962 is my theme name, tleft is a class to my thumbnail image.

Comment: Nikhil, thanks. I try this code: `<?php
function resep962_preprocess_image(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['style_name'])) {
    $vars['attributes']['class'][] = drupal_html_class($vars['style_name']);
  }
}
?>` this code result an image with image-style-name as class (img.thumbnail, img.medium, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Hi create custom image style in admin section for the following url

http://www.example.com/admin/config/media/image-styles

then you will set in views section, after adding image field in views you need to find **image style** drop down option to select your created custom style

hope fully help this.